# onSurfaceCreated() is not called when activity resumes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, surfaceview

I'm stuck with a `SurfaceView` issue, and this problem seems to be related with any misunderstanding of how these `SurfaceView` callbacks work.

Let's try to solve this theorethicaly:

I have an activity **A**, hosting a `fragment` which is drawing an object in real time, running a `thread` to acomplish this task (calling the drawing method of my `View` periodically and drawing it on the `SurfaceView`).

Then I switch to activity **B**, which hosts another fragment showing some UI.
Whenever I switch to this activity **B**, I can see the `SurfaceView` is being destroyed, so the `onSurfaceDestroyed()` callback is called and I stop my drawing thread there.

Everything pretty fine and obvious by now, but when I go back to activity **A**, the `SurfaceView` is not being created, so the `onSurfaceCreated()` is not called, and thus my drawing thread won't start.
By debugging, I can see my `View` exists when I come back from **B** to **A**, and it could be drawn if the thread was running, but for my thread to run, I need the `SurfaceView` to be created again.

So, my **question** (edited):
Why the `SurfaceView` isn't being created when I'm back to fragment **A** if fragment is visible?

*I'm sorry I can't provide any code for this question but it's more theorethycal than any other kind.*

**EDIT: Progress update**

---

After doing some more research and testing, I've realized that any fragment's `onCreateView()`is only called once in it's lifetime, untill it's removed from the fragment manager and no longer managed by the framework.

`SurfaceView` is destroyed when the fragment which is using it becomes no longer visible, before calling it's `onDestroyView()`, but sadly (and I don't understand why) **it is not recreated when it becomes visible again**, and this is the source of my problem. I need that `SurfaceView` to be created again when that fragment becomes visible so it can launch my drawing thread as the framework calls `onSurfaceCreated()`.

The layout I'm trying to draw consists of two views, one is managed by the framework and the other is drawn using the SurfaceView. When I come back to Activity **A** from **B**, I know the fragment is visible because I can see the view managed by the framework drawn appropriately, but no trace of the one managed by the thread which starts when the `SurfaceView` is created, as this `SurfaceView` hasn't been created.

Comment: If the SurfaceView's `onSurfaceDestroyed()` is being called, then the `onSurfaceCreated()` should be called. `onSurfaceChanged()` is called when the surface's size or format changes. Note these are called by the app framework -- never call them from the app. Some additional notes can be found here: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm letting the framework call those callbacks con its own, but the problem seems to be that I'm not instantiating the view which has to be drawn properly inside the A fragment. I debugged again and found that fragment A isn't calling `onCreateView()` but `onResume()` when it I get back to activity A from activity B and the fragment is displayed. Quite a mess to explain :P. Tomorrow I'll try to figure out this odd behaviour.

Comment: @fadden I've updated the question with a little more information. `onSurfaceCreated()` is not triggered when fragment becomes visible again although `onSurfaceDestroyed()` was called when fragment was no longer visible due to the activity switch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I still don't know why the android framework won't create the `SurfaceView` on it's own, but all I had to do was to force the `View`'s visibility to `VISIBLE`and that did the trick. `SurfaceHolder` callbacks started to work as expected when I explicitly told the `View` to be visible in the `onResume()` method of the `Fragment`:

```
myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: All I meant to do with my answer was to actually answer the question. `SurfaceView` wasn't created (I think) because the visibility of the `view` might not had been `VISIBLE`. Anyway, if you think it's better to edit the question and keep it open, I would edit it adding this new info.

Comment: I think this is best as an answer, as you have done. Perhaps the other commenters did not understand that this solves your problem, even though it is still a mystery why Android did not do this on its own.